# How to detect changes in form control value in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am working on an angular 4 project. In which, I have a requirement to split the form into multiple components, I want to detect one form control change in the another component.

```
@Input() TipsControl  : FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {
  this.onProviderChange();
}  
onProviderChange(){
  this.TipsControl.controls['provider_details'].valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    console.log("hello");
    this.tipProviderBlockStatus = false;
    this.ParkingProviderBlockStatus = false;
    this.bonusProviderBlockStatus = false;
  });
}
```

I used the above code however it works only once i.e when page is init.. What I want is that whenever the value of this control is changed it should call this function. Any help or suggestion to achieve the same would be highly appreciated

Comment: Make `TipsControl` a `BehaviourSubject<FormGroup>` on a `service.ts` file. Then have two methods that `set` the `TipsControl` value and `get` the `TipsControl` value as `Observable<FormGroup>`.  Then inject that service to both components and subscribe to the service. So change detection can be implemented in vice-versa. That's how I would do it.

Comment: For bigger apps you should use ngrx/store or angular-redux/store. This way different  components and services communicate through central managed subjects.

Comment: I don't know if you can use:  @Input()  set TipsControl  (tipsControl: string) {    this.TipsControl =tipsControl || undefined'; onProviderChange()  }

Comment: Maybe just a change event would do? click, change, input... ?